# Why am I getting this error in unity c# and how do i fix it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to make a pause menu in unity and it says i can't make a function public. Why can't I?

It says

> CS0106 The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item    Assembly-CSharp, Assembly-CSharp.Player C:\Users\Jaspin\CubeGame\Assets\UI\Paused\PauseMenu.cs  47  Active

for all three.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject pauseMenuUI;

    public static bool GameIsPaused = false;

    void Start()
    {

        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (GameIsPaused)
            {
                Resume();
            } else
            {
                Pause();
            }
        }

        void Resume()
        {
            pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
            Time.timeScale = 1f;
            GameIsPaused = false;
        }

        void Pause()
        {
            pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
            GameIsPaused = true;
        }

        public void LoadMenu()
        {
            Debug.Log("Loading menu...");
        }

        public void QuitGame()
        {
            Debug.Log("Quiting game...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Resume (etc) are functions, *local* to Update. You missed a }

Answer (score 1):

You are using nested functions. `LoadMenu` is a nested function in `Update`. Nested function can't have visibility modifiers.

You probably missed a `}` in line 32.